# Where the object that moves along the intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y+z=1$ needs to be if we want the sum $x+2y+z$ to be max/min?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> An object is moving along the curve which is derived from the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $y+z=1$. Where does the object need to be located if we want to maximize/minimize the sum $x+2y+z$? What is the min/max sum?

I'm really not sure how to determine the constraint function. The intersection of the cylinder and the plane is:
$$
x^2+(1-z)^2=1
$$
Then:
$$
z=\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}
$$
I guess we can define new function:
$$
g(x,y)=x+2y+z=x+2y+\frac{x^2+z^2}{2}=x+2y+\frac{x^2+(1-y)^2}{2}
$$
Then we can look for critical points:
$$
g_x=1+x\\
g_y=1+y
$$
Which means that $(-1,-1)$ is the critical point. I don't see how to proceed though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @StackTD yes I am

Comment: Alright; then one way would be to use two Lagrange multipliers - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An object is moving along the curve which is derived from the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $y+z=1$. Where does the object need to be located if we want to maximize/minimize the sum $x+2y+z$? What is the min/max sum?

So you're looking for the extreme values of $f(x,y,z) = x+2y+z$ for points $(x,y,z)$ located on the cylinder $\color{blue}{x^2+y^2=1}$ **and** on the plane $\color{red}{y+z=1}$; i.e. on their intersection. Introduce two Lagrange multipliers to limit the points to those on this intersection:
$$\begin{align}F(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu) & = f(x,y,z)+\lambda \left( \color{blue}{x^2+y^2 -1} \right)+\mu \left( \color{red}{y+z -1} \right) \\
& = x+2y+z+\lambda \left( \color{blue}{x^2+y^2 -1} \right)+\mu \left( \color{red}{y+z -1} \right)\end{align}$$ 
Now you solve the system:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
F_x = 0 \\
F_y = 0 \\
F_z = 0 \\
F_\lambda = 0 \\
F_\mu = 0
\end{array}\right. \iff \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
F_x = 0 \\
F_y = 0 \\
F_z = 0 \\
\color{blue}{x^2+y^2=1} \\
\color{red}{y+z=1}
\end{array}\right. \iff \ldots$$

Can you proceed?

---

Addition after comments. In your notation with
$$\color{green}{p(x,y,z)=x+2y+z \implies \nabla p = \langle 1,2,1\rangle }$$
the function to be optimized and constraints
$$\color{blue}{j(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-1 \implies \nabla j = \langle 2x,2y,0 \rangle}$$
and
$$\color{red}{k(x,y,z)=y+z-1 \implies \nabla k = \langle 0,1,1 \rangle}$$
the system becomes:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\color{green}{\nabla p} = \lambda \color{blue}{\nabla j} + \mu \color{red}{\nabla k} \\
\color{blue}{j(x,y,z)=0} \\
\color{red}{k(x,y,z)=0}
\end{array}\right. \iff
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
1=2\lambda x \\
2 = 2\lambda y + \mu \\
1 = \mu \\
\color{blue}{x^2+y^2=1} \\
\color{red}{y+z=1}
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I've never seen using multiple Lagrange multipliers, I'll try. If $p(x,y,z)=x+2y+z$, $j(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ and $k(y,z)=y+z-1$ then $\nabla p=\langle 1,2,1\rangle$, $\nabla j=\langle 2x,2y\rangle$, $\nabla k=\langle 1,1\rangle$ then is the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
1=c2x\\
2=c(2y+1)\\
1=c
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @user123429842 You used $c$ twice? You need two (different) Lagrange multipliers, for the two constraints $j$ and $k$ (in your notation). And don't forget to add the constraints to your system (blue & red in my answer).

Comment: Like this:$$
\begin{cases}
1=\lambda 2x\\
2=\lambda 2y\\
2=\mu\\
1=\mu
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @user123429842 There's still some things missing; I've added a bit to my answer to follow your notation.

Comment: I got it finally! Is it a general rule that if you have several multipliers that the gradient of the maximization function $(x+2y+z)$ equals the sum of other gradients?

Comment: Yes, in case of more than one constraint: you introduce a Lagrange multiplier for each constraint and you take the sum.

Answer (score 3):

Express $z$ and we are interested in maximum/minimum of $E = x+y+1$. By the Cauchy inequality we have: $$|x+y|\leq \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)} = \sqrt{2}$$ So $E_{\max} = 1+\sqrt{2}$ which is reached at $x=y=1/\sqrt{2}$ and  $E_{\min} = 1-\sqrt{2}$ which is reached at $x=y=-1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Why $3$.......?

Comment: The thing we're not taught Cauchy method in our class. I know it's not your concern of course, but if I were to use the critical points method what would be my function? $E=x+y+1$ doesn't have any of course.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, The set of points $P(x,y)$ which satysfies $x^2+y^2=1$ is circle  and thus compact and $E$ (which is continous) is defined on iz so it must have max and min.

Answer (score 2):

Polar coordinates, parameter$ t: 0 \le t \lt 2π.$

$x =\cos(t), y =\sin(t)$,

$ z =1- \sin(t)$;

Function $f$:

$f(t) : = x(t)+ 2y(t) + z(t).$

$f(t) = \cos(t) + 2\sin(t) +1 - \sin(t)$;

$f(t)  = \cos(t) + \sin(t) +1$;

1) Note :

$\cos(π/4)= \sin(π/4)= (1/2)√2 = \frac{1}{√2}$

$f(t) = $

$√2 (\sin(π/4)\cos(t) +$

$\cos(π/4)\sin(t)) + 1$;

$f(t) = √2 \sin(t +π/4) + 1$.

$\max(f(t)) = √2+ 1$, at  $ t = π/4$.

$\min(f(t)) = 1 - √2 $, at  $ t = 5/4 π.$